# Normalizing a table with different structures

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-normalization

I have a normalized table (table a) and a non-normalized table (table b), like this:

[image]

I want to insert a new row into the normalized table for each parent in the non-normalized table. So if there is a record in table B with two parents for a studentID, I want to insert two records into table A with each different parent name from table B.

I've been struggling for with this for hours, any help would be appreciated on how to go about doing this.

Comment: AN sql query to insert the data from one table into another.

Comment: Can you add the table layouts in text format?  I can't see the image.

Comment: I updated my answer with a way to do it with pivot.  I don't have a sql server around to try it, but let me know if it doesn't work and what error it gives you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `parentID` is an auto incremental column, you could do this:

```
INSERT INTO NormalizedFamily(studentID, parentName)
SELECT studentID, parentName1
FROM FlatFamily
UNION
SELECT studentID, parentName2
FROM FlatFamily
WHERE parentName2 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT studentID, parentName3
FROM FlatFamily
WHERE parentName3 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT studentID, parentName4
FROM FlatFamily
WHERE parentName4 IS NOT NULL
```

In any case, I don't really get why the column `parentId` is the key of your normalized table. As it is, the same parent can't have multiple students related to him?, shouldn't the key be a combination of `parentID` and `studentID`?.

Comment: it looks like you have a copy paste error and a failure to line up column names for your union clause.

Comment: @Milimetric - Yes, copy-paste is never my friend. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what `unpivot` is meant for.  It's kind of weird and hard-ish to understand for beginners though.  Here's a totally hacky way to do the same thing that should be easy enough to understand:

```
 insert into NormalizedFamily (parentId, studentId, parentName)
 select p.parentName,
        p.parentId,
        f.studentId
   from Parent p
            inner join
        (select studentId, parentName1 as parentName from FlatFamily
         union all
         select studentId, parentName2 as parentName from FlatFamily
         union all
         select studentId, parentName3 as parentName from FlatFamily
         union all
         select studentId, parentName4 as parentName from FlatFamily
         union all
         select studentId, parentName5 as parentName from FlatFamily
        ) t                on t.parentName = p.parentName
```

Here is how `unpivot` would work.  It basically turns columns into rows.  So try out this select statement:

```
 SELECT studentId, parentColumnName, parentName
   FROM (SELECT studentId, parentName1, parentName2, parentName3, parentName4, parentName5
           FROM FlatFamily) f
UNPIVOT (parentName FOR parentColumnName IN (parentName1, parentName2, parentName3, parentName4, parentName5)) AS t
```

Comment: Actually, in this case it would be `UNPIVOT`

Comment: It says Invalid object name 'Parent'.

Comment: @user1319343, I just joined to a table I assumed you had in your schema.  If you don't have a parent table, how are you going to get the parentId?