# Un-normalize a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a normalized table (table a) and a non-normalized table (table b), like this:

[image]

Basically, for each row in table a for the same student ID, I want to read all the parents with the same studentId and put the data into one row in table B.

So if I have 3 rows in table A, then there would be one row in table B with 3 of the 4 parent fields filled in. Any help for an SQl query for this would be appreciated.

Sample for data in table A

```
parentID studentID parentName
1         1         test
2         1          test1
```

Result I want in table B

```
studentID parent1 parent2
1         test    test1
```

Comment: What does this accomplish that a view wouldn't accomplish?

Comment: can you post some sample data and then the desired result?

Comment: Your first table isn't normalised for starters. ParentName should be in Parents. View (or just a straight query) with a pivot is the way I'd approach this. If for some reason I really needed the second table, I'd be looking at triggering off the first, and that would mean ParentID1, ParentID2 etc, otherwise you could never guarantee any data integrity, or you'd have to overwrite each record, verey time one of the "four" changed in the other one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Normalizing a table with different structures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653056/normalizing-a-table-with-different-structures)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a query that would generate the flat results you are looking for.  Is there a reason you couldn't just make this a view instead of permanently restructuring your data?

```
with RankedNormalizedFamily as (
  select
    ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by studentid ORDER BY parentid) as rank
    ,parentID
    ,studentID
    ,parentName
  from
    NormalizedFamily
)
select
  studentID
  ,max(case when rank = 1 then parentName end) as parentName1
  ,max(case when rank = 2 then parentName end) as parentName2
  ,max(case when rank = 3 then parentName end) as parentName3
  ,max(case when rank = 4 then parentName end) as parentName4
from
  RankedNormalizedFamily f
group by
  studentID
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91843/9

To push this data into `FlatFamily` you would use an `INSERT...SELECT`:

```
insert into FlatFamily
select
  studentID
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

So, without knowing what version of what database you are using I am going to just give you the basics and a sample query that *may* work in your system.

Basically you are looking at creating a "Pivot Query" but in order to do this for your query you will need to use an analytic function to designate row numbers for each row returned from table A:

```
select studentID,
       parentID
        row_number() over (partition by studentID order by studentID) as parentNum
FROM NormalizedFamily
order by studentID
```

Then using the results from that you will want to put your pivot query together:

```
select studentID, 
MAX(case when parentNum = 1 then parentID else null),
MAX(case when parentNum = 2 then parentID else null)
MAX(case when parentNum = 3 then parentID else null)
MAX(case when parentNum = 4 then parentID else null)
from (select studentID,
           parentID
            row_number() over (partition by studentID order by studentID) as parentNum
    FROM NormalizedFamily
    order by studentID)
```

You may have to clean up the syntax to work with your database, but that is the general gist of it.